# Python matplotlib how to display more ticks

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The following code generates a graph with few ticks but I need to display a tick every 4 or 6 hours. How can that we accomplished?

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
# Plot train and test so you can see where we have split
gdf = x_test[['AllAPIs']] \
    .rename(columns={'AllAPIs': 'Test Set'}) \
    .join(x_train.rename(columns={'AllAPIs': 'Training Set'}),
          how='outer')
ax = gdf.plot(figsize=(12,5),title='API Calls')
plt.xticks(
    rotation=45,
    horizontalalignment='right',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='medium',
)
plt.show()
```

The output graph is this:
[image]

If I add the HourLocator as follows, I lose my ticks:

```
# set monthly locator
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.HourLocator(interval=4))
# set formatter
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d %H'))
```

[image]

What am I missing?????

Comment: The hour tick will have a maximum of 1000 tickets. Given that there is more than 1000 points in` mdates.HourLocator` I suspect there to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you set the `ticks` from the `plt` object?

```
plt.xticks(
    ticks = gdf.index.values
    rotation=45,
    horizontalalignment='right',
    fontweight='light',
    fontsize='medium',
)
```

This might set a lot of values, however, you can easily construct the `xticks` parameter based on the index.

For example, asumming index values are sorted:

```
start = gdf.index.values[0]
end = gdf.index.values[-1]

ticks = pd.date_range(start, end, freq='4H')
labels = [x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H') for x in ticks]

plt.xtics(ticks=ticks, labels=labels)
```

Comment: setting ticks from plt object throws an error: ConversionError: Failed to convert value(s) to axis units: array(['2020-02-18 00:00:00', '2020-02-18 01:00:00',
       '2020-02-18 02:00:00', ..., '2020-04-06 21:00:00',
       '2020-04-06 22:00:00', '2020-04-06 23:00:00'], dtype=object)

Comment: If you are using a dates on  index, why is your dtype as `object`?, it should be datetime,  so first do: `gdf['index'] = pd.to_datetime(gdf.index.values)` and then `gdf.set_index('index', inplace=True)`

Comment: you're absolutely correct, I was converting it unnecessarily during import step. Final code now shows correct ticks. Thanks!!!!!!